# How to prevent narrowing generic types while using literals with currying in typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a problem designing types for Sanctuary (js library for functional programming). I'd like to create `Ord` type, representing any value that has natural order. `Ord` is either:

1. Some built-in primitive type: `number`, `string`, `Date`, `boolean`
2. Any user type implementing required interface (`compareTo` method)
3. An array of `Ord`s

To express it, I used (which seems natural to me) union type (with slight workaround over making recurring types possible), like:

```
type Ord = boolean | Date | number | string | Comparable<any> | OrderedArray

interface OrderedArray extends Array<Ord> {}
```

(any code I mention is available at this [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOU4BGANhADwAqAfMgN4BQyyCWuUE56AFOmABbQAuZOQCUQkAFdMBaHQC+dOmACe2FAHkoAE2QBeZAXToScEMgA+yACJxIF5JOnR7AZzBRQAc3sYceQiSkpsrUlppa0BBaAIJQ+MqKoJCwiBrakTFxcMrIEAAekCBaLsix8aTh1DQKdMwgbkwseCj6FLkFEEUllZx5QqJ61JzK-SKDyAAMANyKAPSzwrzAJeggKLguLhAlcCX5agiQWrVNbJwA2gCMADTIAEwAuiIXAMy3ACxPcwumOnzLyFWKHgwCIOz2eQORxOfjOV1uj2e5zeyHOny+dHmyAA7igEKYHNswMhdshMMESVllOCcShsaCiDDWBALvD7g8nqyXg9bmiOSJFMxYSzzvAwRBOaK4OKMQgiLsSgAxIy0BiNYUcbh8QTIZXoMb0RiMNhgCRQMzTNU1RgwIwAZQOwBgwAQnANauNEFN5uQ7zuM0YChqcoVyAAQnhVYwhczNTx+FAhBGoO6jcgTWaLQHkEHvsgQWCSRCoVFbi5QEhdSrfuHI80HDx1bgwMACKCUJwtBIUGB0Pn7Y7nQgyV7eOgtAKY81OGtsVWuCJnrPa1A3QLavLNrWAF60GpYgsuW6kiO7rTobYgADkxOAOBImE6xN8rACECZ0+Xp7XM4gc+-i6KJiPxFMg-wlIetzYgmECksAxIuGOEhEFo15gAAdJhH5nJczwvAKQA)).

Then, to create type definitions for e.g. `compare` function, I used generic type with type constraint, i.e. something like (note it is curried):

```
function compare<T extends Ord>(a: T): (b: T) => number
```

Unfortunately, while using such an approach with literal arguments, e.g. (`compare(2)(3)`, which is perfectly valid code), typescript errors out, with `'3' is not assignable to '2'`. It seems that with first argument provided, typescript narrows down type parameter to `2` (literal type containing only `2` value), whereas it should be narrowed down only to `number`. Is there any way to prevent him from doing this? Or any other working approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured it out (at least in a way that *works*, not necesserily the best one). It turned out that adding explicit overloads for all types that have literal representation, and therefore could be narrowed, fixes it, like:

```js
function compare(x: number): (y: number) => number;
function compare(y: string): (y: string) => number;
function compare(x: boolean): (y: boolean) => number;

// and generic overload
function compare<T extends Ord>(x: T): (y: T) => number;
function compare<T extends Ord>(x: T): (y: T) => number {
  ...
};
```

I think these explicit overloads take precedence in signature resolution, and thus my problem is gone, like:

```
compare(2)(3) // resolves to compare(x: number)(y: number)
```

Solution is available at [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOU4BGANhADwAqAfMgN4BQyyCWuUE56AFOmABbQAuZOQCUQkAFdMBaHQC+dOmACe2FAHkoAE2QBeZAXToScEMgA+yACJxIF5JOnR7AZzBRQAc3sYceQiSkpsrUlppa0BBaAIJQ+Mp0oJCwiBrakTFxcMrIEAAekCBaLsix8aTh1DQKigD0tcjoAG7QROhwxcgw6FC5LVA52B6YwGDALcgqanQwEiAIY+hmzH5snHniUjJQYsicyptOO3rUjtsA3DNzC8BLTCx4EPtCbh4gnrvPyK9eIicOW2gl1m80Wyweaw2BiMJhAnwO0OMEFMf10p0BUEudHqyFMOk8EBA0GACEa-TaHSuoNu4NWZHIuQKhM6lXWQlEQi+on+ZyBVJudxWrHpjMKLO0lDZwnh7NR6KOtAYyDYYAkUDMIIFIC5f3ojEYKrVZgADJdGAo5FiceReMASksULgXC4ICU4CV8moFlE6ELHpwANoARgANMgAEwAXREgYAzGGACzRuoNPGTW32oldODAIhuj15L2QLS+iFPYNhqMxgPx5ABpPJ7ENADuKAQpgcrrAuJKmGCuKyynzyFbI9zRFLdMDFYjkej09jkbD9bnIkUvqI7pKADEjIrGH62BxuHxBMhd+hdUqDRBVerkKalTVGN10ABlL3AGAkzhX-XK28jWQBNwzNZALUUBBN2dZAACE8H3e46WPHh+CgIR4OOPV9UNe9H3NeQU2zXNh09CBvS0MMXFAJBzz3NNMIHFAQB4JDcDGAhcxQTgtAkFAwHQLojA-civxJZBMFvXh0C0NdDyeIlmzorgRBjRS4LwX81ybZAnRdFxJ2FQN1IvX95wDEyjDM7SoK3DSAC9aBqHF4BIsN3Qc5AtHQV0QAAcm7YAcBISTwDQCEAggQz-XU+D7K0zhYrgeLVKIlilNGXSt1daK1iDGNYzXIA).

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the type system to do the literal widening yourself if the compiler [doesn't do it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) (such as the case here where `T` has a contextual type including `string`, `number`, and `boolean`):

```
type Widen<T> = 
  T extends string ? string : 
  T extends number ? number : 
  T extends boolean ? boolean : 
  T;

const compare = <T extends Ord>(x: T) => (y: Widen<T>) => 0;
```

So `x` will stay narrow, but `y` will be widened.  This will allow the following call:

```
compare(1)(3);  // <1>(x: 1) => (y: number) => number
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Q0f4rBBBA0FPLBEDwdhSFcTxcBYWh24CgA1nkd5ahxpIUkyzK+nQmq3PcU5sEIpAUpQXxCLJ4IAuIyzQGC+jUBs0B0EAA)

---

UPDATE: in case you really want to be able to optionally keep `T` narrow, you can do the following complicated thing:

```
type OptionallyWiden<X, T> = 
   [X] extends [never] ? 
     T extends string ? string : 
     T extends number ? number : 
     T extends boolean ? boolean : 
     T
  : T;

const compare = <X extends Ord = never, T extends Ord = X>(x: T) => (
  y: OptionallyWiden<X, T>
) => 0;
```

which gives you this behavior:

```
compare(1)(3); // okay
// const compare: <never, 1>(x: 1) => (y: number) => number

compare<1 | 2>(1)(3); // error now
//  ------------> ~
// 3 is not assignable to 1 | 2
// const compare: <1 | 2, 1 | 2>(x: 1 | 2) => (y: 1 | 2) => number
```

It works by using two type parameters... the first one, `X`, will default to `never` unless manually specified.  If `X` is `never`, the inferred value of `T` will be widened.  If `X` is not `never`, the specified value will be used and not widened.

Is the flexibility here worth the weird clunky type juggling?  I guess it's up to you to figure out, but I'd probably just leave the original `<T extends Ord>(x: T) => (y: T) => 0` if I wanted flexibility to have both narrow and wide `T` values, and just manually widen `T` if that's what I want.

Anyway, hope this helps again!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOU4BGANhADwAqAfMgN4BQyyCWuUE56AFOmABbQAuZOQCUQkAFdMBaAG46AXzp0wAT2woA8lAAmyALzIC6dCTghkAH2QAROJCvJJ06I4DOYKKADmjjDjxCElJzVWprbR1oCB0AQSh8VXllUEhYRC1daLiEuFVkCAAPSBAdN2R4xNJI6holFXUtbDBgdBA4IiJVAHVgKJBSAA0AGmFqQwZGAG1BgF0C4ohS8qmQCAA3aHmAfmRJxmEFkrLkDy8QX12zn2QhfcZyI6WT5xkoZF3X1zuDh6flowmMwWXbGUwQcy3Pa-YSTITkZLMEAeJgsPAoQxDf4nSIGJwbaCjR5FY7lXGGQaUTiFeEiAzUTiTVRCTTNVrtTo9PpLIZEyh0On6agABmSAHoxcJeMBym0ULg3G4IOU4OUihoEJAdHRmAE2JwpgBGUYAJlmIgNAGZRgAWc3iyXmPR8GXIOXIeDAIgqtWFDVanVo-VG03mq2jKZ2+3KCXIADuKAQkLWKNVyEwoWQeESPvjKDjXqIgb1EANIeQZrDUymltmEajIkRQdLU3g3ogVbbSujOqIqvKADETLRJrrWOwuDx+FAhEP0HT6L82GAJFALKLJvVGDATABlDXAGDABCcBf3Zeriw2k3yRhKeoIPuK5AAITwI8YY-RHG4fEEr7wM8lwgFc12QDc70UGNJU9b0s19f0YlGNxQCQZA5yzUoAPedEnB4VEAhaAgvRQTgdAkFAwHQD09wPI8EHTEDeHQHQRGLcdODWON0JMU8LS47C+MRJ9yjfAAvWh6ljWC3FGNNxOQHR0GVEAAHIwGQYAcBITAlg0-xWCCCB2PRTiIG48S+LMiy4DEoTlC-fVDQtS1G2QWN0AAazyOhYyRFFHIgIRSDWTYoFGQ0qRpZBnPpZBOGZJwpDeQVqC+KAHObUhDUcE0qWczhXNkdzJWgKB0HeEB0DjXzJWQABaRqmuaxrqAAP1q5BLU08oqo0-tgG8dpiEo6icusE1Ov8jTAuC8aKwi3KoqEeaTVS+LEtW9b0uUIA)

Comment: Hmm, widening types freely feels insecure to me. What if I'd like to explicitly specify type parameter to some e.g. number union type? Second parameter would get widened to `number` and potentially fail if I provide an invalid value? E.g. `compare<1 | 2 | 3>(2)(42)` would, counterintuitively, pass type checking.

Comment: I updated this answer if you want more flexibility with this method

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify definition of `Ord`, all tests pass.

```js
interface Comparable<T> {
  compareTo(other: T): number
}

type Ord<T> = T | Comparable<T> | Array<T>

const compare = <T extends Ord<any>>(x: T) => (y: T) => 0;
```

TypeScript Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOU4BGANhADwAqAfMgN4BQyyCWuUE56AFOmABbQAuZOQCUQkAFdMBaHQC+dOmACe2FAHkoAEwrUAvMOQAfNCzyESu48gCCUfMt2LmIAM5gmZtsgMVkEAA9IEC1XZE0dOBBlSkpOAKFRH2pOZUSRZOQABgBuRQB6fOFeYDD0EBRcV1cIMLgwwLUESC06Zhw8CE4AbQBGABpkACYAXREegGZBgBYxgqKorWQ+UuRylHhgIjqGgKaWtq8uvsHR8e6p5G7ZubpC5AB3FAQo5Ar3ZHrkTCjlT-s4Modo8UA8tkRDh02D0TsMRmMYRMRoNrvCRM4jj14NsIAjutiarcEER6mEAGLodC0BieKHsLg8fhQIQU9AZeiMRhsMASKAgbJ5RgKGkwSkAZSawBgwAQnHZNK5EB5fOQ0yGguQCmFxNJyAAQnhqYx2qx6dw+IJ9Xh5ZzkNzefzcjStfNkJttp9dvsIFpBq5QEhkKzPiErVB-igQDxabgwMACFsUJwtBIUGAqaL0BKIAgpTLvkreOgtOiTZ1OBUHkHKXLxpWw7XFHcFqGVmF3a5Bg8mRAvsAPK4ixIiFoQAByMAAOmnkNNnF64wm6KAA).

I am not sure, though, if this fits all other requirements for the library.

Comment: It's incorrect, it allows passing instances of user types that don't implement `Comparable` interface. Effectively, we throw away whole type system with it.

Comment: Can you add test in your playground example which asserts this rule?

Comment: @MichałKaczanowicz According to your definitions, this is also valid: `compare([[1, 2]])([[3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 8]])` method call?

Comment: Yes, I can nest arrays, compare's implementation (not shown here for simplicity sake) works recursively in such a case.

Comment: OK. I think narrowing is there because you have circular reference between `Ord` and `OrderedArray` in type definition. Not sure how to avoid that.